# Spring Boot: OAuth endpoint redirects to 8443

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a web-app running with SSL only (no http allowed) on port 8080:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: file:${SERVER_KEYSTORE_PATH}
    key-store-password: ${SERVER_CERT_PASSWORD}
  port: 8080
```

When I launch the app, I see in the logs:

```
2020-03-17 17:32:29.836  INFO 90960 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (https)
```

One of my endpoints (the root one, actually) is protected by Spring Security, OAuth2:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String baseURI = redirectURI.substring(redirectURI.lastIndexOf("/"));
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .redirectionEndpoint().baseUri(baseURI);
    }
```

The problem is that when I go to https://localhost:8080 - it redirects me to https://localhost:8443/oauth2/authorization/oauth So, for some reason the port 8080 is overriden with 8443.

As far as I understood from similar questions, this is happening because Tomcat is trying to redirect the user to the SSL-enabled endpoint (https) from the plain endpoint (http). But my endpoint is already SSL-enabled, so I don't really understand why is it happening. If I go to any other endpoint, it works with https and 8080 port - so only protected endpoint is problematic.

I tried to customize `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` with `ConnectorCustomizers` and set there redirect port to `8080`, but it didn't help.

Any ideas on how to disable this useless redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8140#issuecomment-600980028 :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    PortMapperImpl portMapper = new PortMapperImpl();
    portMapper.setPortMappings(Collections.singletonMap("8080","8080"));
    PortResolverImpl portResolver = new PortResolverImpl();
    portResolver.setPortMapper(portMapper);
    LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(
            "/login");
    entryPoint.setPortMapper(portMapper);
    entryPoint.setPortResolver(portResolver);
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
        //...
        ;
}
```